# Anatomy of an animal with one foreleg

Tags: creature-design, anatomy, tetrapods

The animal is a tetrapoid, and has a single foreleg placed medially (in the sagittal plane) with two fully tetrapodal hindlegs. The internal anatomy, at least regarding the muscles and bones of the foreleg and shoulder, should be symmetrical and stick to the tetrapodal structure (though a doubled humerus is acceptable if necessary). The anatomy must also be realistically functional as a leg and able to work as an ungulate-like form

**What is the closest anatomy to normal tetrapods that satisfies the criteria given above?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130798/discussion-on-question-by-ichthys-king-anatomy-of-an-animal-with-one-foreleg).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The humeri could be curved inward and meet at the elbow, and hidden inside the body like a bird's hindlimbs. The opposite ulnas and radii could either be fused so that there is only 1 ulna and 1 radius, or the 4 bones can just run parallel to each other and fuse at the wrist bones.

Comment: Do try to refrain from answering questions that are unclear, being edited or in the close queue!

Comment: I thought I understood the question fine @elemtilas, it is just worded in a rather peculiar way.

Comment: It's not so much about understanding as about waiting until the issues are settled.  Poorly worded questions are a problem in this forum, and people jumping the gun to answer them even though the question is in the close queue and has active calls for clarification  is also a problem. I'm not singling you out -- I've done the same thing myself! The problem is that we're communicating to new (and old) users that we don't need to care about question quality here because, hey, it's just fiction!